# CMake: Could not find Python3 (found version 3.9.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake

I am trying to configure CMake (v3.26.0) to find a local Anaconda installation of Python3 (on Ventura 13.3.1) I am using but I am running into an issue with CMake detecting Python. In my CMake configuration script, I have:

```
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter REQUIRED
             Python3_ROOT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../conda/bin")
```

This correctly points CMake to the location of the local Python3 interpreter. Moreover, when I run the configuration script, it *appears* to find Python but seems to think it hasn't:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.26.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Python3 (missing: Python3_ROOT
  /Users/xxx/xxxxx/cmake/../conda/bin) (found version "3.9.6")
```

I am confused; it seems to be picking up the right version of Python (i.e., I expect it to be 3.9.6) but CMake is somehow indicating that it wasn't found. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look at the full signature of [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#full-signature), there's no argument `Python3_ROOT`. However, after `REQUIRED` comes `[[COMPONENTS] [components...]]` meaning that anything at that point will be understood as a component.

[CMake's doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#basic-signature) puts it like this:

> As a form of shorthand, if the REQUIRED option is present, the COMPONENTS keyword can be omitted and the required components can be listed directly after REQUIRED.

CMake fails to find a component of Python3 called "Python3_ROOT" and consequently reports a failure: Python3_ROOT was not found.

To give CMake paths to look for a package, use the `PATHS` or `HINTS` arguments like this:

```
find_package(Python3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter
             PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../conda/bin)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Friedrich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76374186/2548285), I realized that I had the `REQUIRED` command out of order and was mis-applying the [Python3 root directory hint](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython3.html). The correct, working configuration is:

```
SET(Python3_ROOT_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../conda/bin")
find_package(Python3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter)
```

This correctly locates my Conda-based Python installation.